# Question for Advaitins: If I am Brahman, then why do I (who is already Brahman) need to find out that I am Brahman? Who is this “I”?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta

1. I am Brahman.
2. I need to find out that I am Brahman. But who is this “I”? “I” refers to Brahman.
3. So, Brahman needs to find out that It (Brahman) is Brahman.

This makes no sense.

Comment: Why it makes no sense? When you are dreaming and find yourself living king’ life. Do you realize that you are actually dreaming? No. Similarly Brahman need to find out that it is brahman by realizing that it is not gross body, not prana, not intellect . Call it maya. Because of maya you don’t know who you are

Comment: This brahman is encompassed in avidya or ignorance that he is not brahman and one realize that he is brahman then his avidya is lost and he becomes brahman.. now this logic makes sense right..But there lot many realized brahman before us right.. then there is only one brahman right if that one brahman is already realized we shouldnt exist right.. there is perpetual chicken and egg problem if you assume the above.. otherwise advaita have perfect answer for all your questions

Comment: @Rahul Brahman is not all knowing. Very very simple. Ishwara is all knowing. Advaita is all about the difference between Ishwara and Brahman. Ishwara is Sarvajna. Brahman is incapable of knowledge, thinking, memory etc. Brahman is only Sacchidananda. Existence Consciousness Bliss. If you have anymore doubts you could ping me here or you could read tattva bodha.

Comment: @ketan Yes, you are right

Comment: @Rahul I had to delete my answer as it was lacking sources. I have posted it as a comment.

Comment: @Rahul the title and the description of the question is very different

Comment: @MrGreenGold Thank you for the discussions and the answer, and for mentioning Tattva Bodha.

Comment: @Rahul I think you should remove “the Brahma is all-knowing” part from the question. Then the title and content of question would be in sync to specific query - why do Brahma needs to find out it is Brahma.

Comment: @Ketan I have removed that part.

Comment: Thanks. I highly recommend this lecture. You will find it helpful https://youtu.be/4JkvlzXczpY

Comment: @Ketan Thank you very much for the link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second point is wrong. 'I' does not refer to Brahman. Here 'I' is the subtle body of Jiva that consists of manas, buddhi, chitta and ahamkara. It is this I that is searching for Brahman.

> Marwari Devotee: "Who is this 'I' that says, 'O Lord, I am Thy
> servant'?"
>
> Sri Ramakrishna:"This is the **lingasarira or embodied soul. It consists
> of manas, buddhi, chitta and ahamkara.**  Lingasarira is the Atman bound
> by the eight fetters. Chitta is the 'I-consciousness' that says
> 'Aha!'"

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 30, The Master in Various Moods**

Fetters are shame, hatred, fear, caste, lineage, good conduct, grief, and secretiveness.

**Some Comments on the nature of Brahman**

The question has been changed. The first version of the question stated that Brahman is all-knowing. Is it a correct description of Brahman? I would like to state that Brahman is **Pure Consciousness** in the Advaita Vedanta scheme. To interpret the Advaita Brahman as jada is completely missing the point. The concepts of 'all-knowing' or 'not all-knowing' can not possibly apply to Pure Consciousness. Such dualistic concepts can apply only to conscious beings. Narayana of Vishistadvaita Vedanta and Vishnu of Dvaita Vedanta are conscious beings and are all-knowing.

It is very difficult to say anything affirmative about Advaita Vedanta Brahman. The description 'Sat-Chid-Ananda' illustrates this point. Brahman may be said to be existence (SAT), be Pure Consciousness (CHID) and be bliss itself (ANAND). The above description is not stating that Brahman exists but what is being claimed is that Brahman is the principle of existence. Similarly Brahman is not a conscious being but consciousness itself and is not blissful but bliss itself.

It is this difficulty that has led to describing Brahman negatively. An example of Brahman described negatively is given below.

> Yajnavalkya said: O Gargi, it is the supreme being that the non-yogins
> call gross but, in fact, that is eternal and wonderful lord; **one that
> is not long, not red, that has no head, that has no setting, hence
> that has a lasting taste, that has no contact, no smell, no juice, no
> eyes, no ears, neither speech nor mind, no brilliance, no proof [or
> magnitude], no (worldly) happiness, no name, no race, no death, no
> age, no ailment; that is nectarine, that is expressed by the word Om,
> that is immortal, that has neither a predecessor nor a successor, that
> is endless and non-external. It eats something. It does not eat
> anything. ..**

**Linga Purana II.9.53–54**

Comment: But isn't it more precise to say that Brahman is not all knowing. Ishwara is all knowing. Advaita is all about the difference between Ishwara and Brahman. Ishwara is Sarvajna. Brahman is incapable of knowledge, thinking, memory etc. Brahman is only Sacchidananda. Existence Consciousness Bliss.

Comment: Brahman and Ishvara are not 2. Vivekananda says, 'Ishvara is the highest manifestation of the Absolute Reality, or in other words, the highest possible reading of the Absolute by the human mind. ' Brahman when experienced by human mind is called Ishvara. One can't say Brahman is not all-knowing because then Ishvara also becomes not all-knowing. We can use anthropomorphic concepts like all-knowing up to Ishvara, Brahman as seen through the mind. There is no way to use such anthropomorphic concepts regarding Brahman.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Comment: What are the 8 fetters?

Comment: Fetters are shame, hatred, fear, pride of caste, hesitation, the desire to conceal etc. The Gospel does not mention the last 2 fetters.

Comment: No no there's something wrong with Brahman being all knowing. If you are Brahman, and Brahman is all knowing then Samsara can't continue. The ego of lingasharira is not you, its the false you. In the statement I am Brahman or Aham Brahmasmi, the I which is used is not the I of Lingasharira. So I Brahman is Sarvajna then I would also be Sarvajna, then there would be no Samsara which is false. Swamiji saying Ishwara is God as we can see it means Ishwara as seen within Maya. Qualities that are not present in Brahman can be seen in Ishwara. That's why Brahman is nirguna but Ishwara is Saguna.

Comment: See Ishwara is blue color but Brahman is colour less in the same way Ishwara is Sarvajna but Brahman is Knowledge less. Moreover over knowing something needs parts. Also Brahman has no mind to know as all knowing happens in mind.

Comment: One can't use any anthropomorphic term to describe Brahman. Brahman is beyond all dualities like all-knowing and not all-knowing. Ishvara is Brahman as viewed in duality and hence is described as all-knowing. The 'I' that wants to experience Brahman is the Ahamkara of the linga sarira. The 'I' of Aham Brahmasmi is what you get after subtracting the body-mind complex of the Jiva, i.e., the Atman.

Comment: Brahman cannot know or think or remember as it does not have manomaya and vijnanamaya kosha. Ofcourse one can't describe Brahman he can be only described as not this and not this. Having said that you can make certain statements. I think you are over philosophising it. For eg one can say Brahman exists, you can't say Brahman is beyong existing and  not existing. Like that Brahman is without gunas. You can't say say Brahman is beyond saguna and nirguna. Brahman is nirguna likewise Brahman is not all knowing and is incapable of knowing anything.

Comment: I suppose the question can be framed in another way. If you are Brahman and Shankaracharya is also Brahman and if Shankaracharya is realised then even you should be realised. Why is this logic wrong.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay Yes, a user named Ketan edited the question title.

Answer (score 5):

There are two question, the title of the question asks a different question and description of the question asks as totally different question.

Title question

> If I am Brahman, and Brahman is all-knowing, then why do I (who is
> already Brahman) need to find out that I am Brahman?

Description question

> 1. I am Brahman.
> 2. I need to find out that I am Brahman. But who is this “I”? “I”
>    refers to Brahman.
> 3. So, Brahman needs to find out that It (Brahman) is Brahman.
>
> This makes no sense.

These both may seem as the same question, but there asking vastly different questions, so I'm going to answer then separately.

---

### Question 1

> If I am Brahman, and Brahman is all-knowing, then why do I (who is
> already Brahman) need to find out that I am Brahman?

Brahman is not all knowing. Very very simple. Ishwara is all knowing. Advaita is all about the difference between Ishwara and Brahman. Ishwara is Sarvajna. Brahman is incapable of knowledge, thinking, memory etc. Brahman is only Sacchidananda. Existence Consciousness Bliss.

There are five koshas or layers

1. Annamaya Kosha
2. Pranamaya Kosha
3. Manomaya Kosha
4. Vijnanamaya Kosha
5. Anandamaya Kosha

Now any knowing and thinking happens only in Manomaya kosha and Vijnanamaya kosha. You know something means the information is stored in Manomaya kosha.

But Brahman is beyond all these five koshas. Brahman can't think, cant remember or know in the colloquial sense. Brahman can only experience and is pure witness alone. It is the inner most core of all the koshas. Whatever thinking and knowing happens in these five koshas which are all inside Maya.

Refer [Tattva Bodha](https://www.v0.chinfo.org/images/userupload/Reflections/02_Tattva_Bodha.pdf)
[image]
[image]

---

### Question 2

> 1. I am Brahman.
> 2. I need to find out that I am Brahman. But who is this “I”? “I”
>    refers to Brahman.
> 3. So, Brahman needs to find out that It (Brahman) is Brahman.
>
> This makes no sense.

Most of such confusing paradoxes arise because one is confusing the Paramarthika truth (Absolute reality outside maya) with Vyavaharika truth (Illusory reality within maya.) The [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48873/22253) by Pradip Gangopadhyay answers this part of question correctly. But this answer doesn't apply to the first part of question.

Let's see this second question.

1. I am Brahman - *This is Paramarthika truth.*
2. I(1) need to find out that I(2) am Brahman. But who is this “I”? “I” refers to Brahman. - *Here the first I, the I(1) who needs to find out the truth, is within maya, so this I(1) is within Vyavaharika level. This I(1), as Pradip pointed out, is the ego of Linga Shareera, but the I(2) is the I at Paramarthika level. So in this statement you are confusing the two truths.*

3. So, Brahman needs to find out that It (Brahman) is Brahman. *Now after resolving statement 2, you can see that statement 3 is wrong. Brahman need not find out anything, as it is there in Paramarthika level*

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto yes have added it.

Comment: Is thinking the property of jaDa padArtha then?

Comment: @zero yes exactly

Comment: @zero Advaita is in line with modern science as computers and robots can also think. Also even according to Dvaita thinking is done by Jada.

Comment: Ok, can you give references from prasthAna traya bhAshyas of Adi Sankaracharya that support this stand?

Comment: @zero But ita clearly given in tattva bodha. But one can find clues about this in Brahma Sutra Bhashya Anadadhikarana, where Shankaracharya argues Brahman is not Anandamaya kosha. So this is then the logical conclusion of it. Thinking and mind will happen in Jada.

Comment: My first preference is for direct statements only from prasthAna traya. Only when they are ruled out, would I look for indirect ones.

Comment: @zero yes check out Anandimayadhikarana

Comment: @zero check this, this is Brahma Sutra Bhashya https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62766.html

Answer (score 2):

The question is a classic question in Advaita Vedanta. Ancient Advaita teachers have dealt with it. In a nutshell, the answer is that in different places, the word "I" is used in different senses: familiar meaning, figurative meaning and indirect meaning.

Here, I am quoting **"Naishkarmasiddhi"**, one of the classics of Advaita Vedanta. This is the work of **Suresvaracharya** (direct disciple of Sankaracharya).

Between the verse II.53 and II.54, Suresvaracharya raised this question. He explained the meaning of the word "I" in the authoritative texts (for example, in the sentence "I am Brahman").

> "We proceed to explain the (different) senses (of the word "I") viz. the familiar meaning ("Prasiddha"), the indirect meaning ("Lakshana"), and the figurative meaning ("Guna")."

Familiar meaning is the primary or usual meaning. Let's take the following example. "Yesterday, I saw a lion in a zoo." Here, by the word "lion", we mean the real lion - the animal. This is the familiar meaning ("Prasiddha"). But, consider the following sentence. When we say, "Devdutta is a lion", it is a figurative usage ("Guna"). It is based on the common qualities of Devdutta and the lion (they are both brave). Now, move on to the third example. When we say "a village on the Ganges", we mean "a village on the bank of the Ganges". This is an indirect use ("Lakshana). Indirect usage is based on proximity (between the Ganges and its bank). But there is no common quality between them.

Now, "I" can be used in these three ways in different situations. In the sentence "I am Brahman", the word "I" is used in a figurative sense ("Guna-Vritti") to represent Brahman.

> "On account of the interiority of the ego-sense to everything else but the pure Self, on account of its subtlety, and because it behaves as if it were the perceiving Self - for these reasons all other notions (Vritti) are discarded and the ego-notion (i.e., the word "I") is chosen to represent the pure Self figuratively." *- Naishkarmasiddhi II.55*

Elsewhere, Suresvaracharya explained that in the text "I am Brahman", the primary or familiar meaning of the word "I" is "ego".

> "As, in the judgement "this post is a man", the notion man cancels the notion "post", so all notion of ego is cancelled by the conviction "I am Brahman (the absolute)." - *Naishkarmasiddhi II.29*

So, basically, "I am Brahman" is not an affirmative identity proposition; rather, it is an affirmative proposition involving concealed negation. In simple words, "this post is a man" really means "this post is not a post, but a man".

Therefore, in the Mahavakya "I am Brahman", whatever sense you choose for the word "I" (familiar or figurative), in any case, the central message remains strict non-duality.

**Reference:**

1. The Realization of the Absolute (Naishkarmasiddhi) by Sri Suresvara translated by A. J. Alston

Comment: 1. *“the word "I" is used in a figurative sense **("Guna-Vritti")** to represent Brahman.”* 2. *“ this post is a man" really means "this post is not a post, but a man.”* - nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as "I" exists Brahman cannot exist, when there is no "I" there is only Brahman. So, what would "I" be if Brahman is the ultimate reality? The "I" is the delusion that you are separated from Brahman. Like a wave ("I") on the ocean (Brahman), and the wave saying it's not the ocean.

It's the root cause of all suffering.

There is no separation. The Jiva just thinks that the Jivatma is separate from Brahman due to ignorance. There is no real answer one can provide to why the Jiva experiences this separation (other than lack of knowledge). It's a bit like asking why did God create the world. We can ponder on it forever, but in the end it's just the ultimate reality. In the same way we cannot define Brahman there are not enough (finite) words to describe it. Same as in how love cannot be understood with words but can only be experienced, and only those who experienced it, understand it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).